# In python how to output str from other class to a pyqt textBrowser

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to show some text on a pyqt window, here is my main window mainUi.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QMessageBox)

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(622, 634)
        '''
        some widget
        '''
        #here is the method I want to use:
        def printf(self,mypstr): 
            self.textBrowser.append(mypstr)
```

The second file is a login window login.py:

```
from PyQt5 import (QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMessageBox, QLineEdit)
from PyQt5.QtCore import  Qt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import main
from mainUi import Ui_MainWindow as uiWindow

class Ui_LoginBox(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def setupLogAccUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Login")
        Dialog.resize(430, 190)
        '''
        some widget
        '''

        if 1==1:
            self.loginBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept) 
            #some text I'm tring to output to the main window:
            uiWindow.printf ('try')
```

Once i run the main it shows: printf() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mypstr', however the first argument in printf(self,mypstr) is self. I have tried two days but cannot get rid off that. Can someone help me for that problem? Thanks first.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: It looks like you need to initialize an instance of uiWindow class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to manipulate the main window from the login dialog. Instead you could use an instance variable or method in the login dialog for communicating the text you want to display and access that from the main window when the dialog has been accepted, e.g.

**login.py**

```
class Ui_LoginBox(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    ....

    def get_text(self):
        return "test"
```

**mainUi.py**

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    ....

    def open_dialog(self):
        dialog = Ui_LoginBox()
        dialog.setupLogAccUi(dialog)
        result = dialog.exec()
        if result == dialog.Accepted:
            self.printf(dialog.get_text())

    def printf(self, mypstr):
        self.textBrowser.append(mypstr)
```

Comment: Appreciate for your help, my problem solved. As you said I should use the method to manipulate other dialog from main window instead of other way around. Again sincerely thanks.